# Can the Bell-LaPadula model emulate the Chinese Wall model?

Tags: information-theory, security, access-control

I have been reading on security policies and the question wether [Bell-LaPadula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell-LaPadula_model) can be used to implement [Chinese Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_wall). Does anyone know more about it?

Comment: Please outline how you think the simulation should work. As it is, the question is a little trite.

Comment: There is a comparison between Chinese Wall & BLP in [the paper by Brewer & Nash](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ninghui/readings/AccessControl/brewer_nash_89.pdf). Is it part of the answer ?

Comment: actually i found the answer by reference book (Computer Security: Art and Science By Matt Bishop)(chapter 7 section 1) suggested by my friend - first the Bell-LaPadula Model cannot capture changes over time. second, more serious problem arises when one considers that subjects in the Chinese Wall model may choose which CDs(company dataset) to access; in other words, initially a subject is free to access all objects. the Bell-LaPadula Model cannot emulate the Chinese Wall model.

Comment: @siddharth, would you like to make your comment the answer?

Comment: @Raphael, if siddharth doesn't answer, can you shift his comment into an answer?

Comment: @Merbs I'm afraid I can't. Feel free to add it as answer yourself (maybe as CW if you don't add anything original).

Answer (score 3):

first the Bell-LaPadula Model cannot capture changes over time. second, more serious problem arises when one considers that subjects in the Chinese Wall model may choose which CDs(company dataset) to access; in other words, initially a subject is free to access all objects. the Bell-LaPadula Model cannot emulate the Chinese Wall model.

Answer (score 2):

Ravi S. Sandhu has given a part of a positive answer in his 1992 paper entitled [Lattice-Based Enforcement of Chinese Walls](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016740489290131A) ([preprint](http://profsandhu.com/journals/csec/csec92-cwall-org.pdf)).
The idea is to build a lattice from the $n$ Conflict Of Interest (COI) classes defined in the Chinese Wall: elements are tuples of the form $[l_1, \ldots, l_n]$ where $l_i$ is either $\bot$ when no document from class $i$ has been accessed yet or a document's identifier from the class $i$.

To capture the dynamic character of the Chinese Wall policy model, the users' labels have to be updated when he/she reads a document pertaining to a COI class. In this sense, the translation is closer to [high-water mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-water_mark_%28computer_security%29) than to *pure* Bell-LaPadula.

Comment: Link-only answers are troublesome because links break; in particular, if the preprint is no longer available, the information content of this answer if zero for all Elsevier-paywalled visitors. Please give a short summary of the article, i.e. at least the core ideas.